# Ms Access query-count values for each row

Tags: ms-access-2010

I want to count the number of fields that contain a value and display at end of each row in an Ms Access query.Any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried creating a report then i use Count() function but haven't succeeded

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744122/2227085) helps